# Grabbing lots of data and passing it to CSV from mutiple dependent Get-Aduser queries

Tags: powershell, variables, active-directory

We have users with minor but annoying differences in naming standards that are loosely followed making scripting a pain. The company has been around a while and depending on who was working in IT when the employee was hired the account could follow any naming convention if followed at all.

In one forest we have accounts that start with `a-`, the manager attribute of that account is the DN of the account owners other/main account without many other common attributes populated. I then need to look up the managers account and grab their `SamAccountName`. Then I need to add `s-` to the `SamAccountName` and do search for that to see if it exists.

Then I need to write the original `SamAccountName`, the second `SamAccountName` and the `s-SamAccountName` and something like a check box if its a valid account name all to a CSV.

without rewriting the script and passing everything to/from a var and then processing that I dont see a way to do it. This script looks up roughly 800 users and processes that three time, so it already takes a while to run without slowing it down with a bunch of var transfers.

```
$test = get-aduser -ldapFilter "(SamAccountName=a-*)" -Server XXX.int:3268 -Properties manager |
Select -ExpandProperty manager | Get-ADUser -Server XXX.int:3268 |
Select -ExpandProperty samaccountname 
$test
```

Comment: Nice story, but what is your question? Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get you started.

```
$test = get-aduser -ldapFilter "(SamAccountName=a-*)" -Server XXX.int:3268 -Properties manager |
    Select-Object SamAccountName,
        @{n='Manager';e={Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Server XXX.int:3268 | Select -Expand SamAccountName}},
        @{n='s-Manager';e={Get-ADUser "s-$($_.Manager)" -Server XXX.int:3268 | Select -Expand SamAccountName}}
$test
```

I am not clear if you need to add `s-` to the manager's or the original account's `SamAccountName`. The script above adds `s-` to the manager's `SamAccountName`.

In scripts where multiple AD lookups are required, sometimes it is best to do one larger lookup and then filter that result for what you need.

**Explanation:**

The main technique of the script makes use of delayed-script binding with the `Select-Object` command. Each user object found by the original `Get-ADUser` command is piped into `Select-Object` and is accessible by the pipeline variable `$_`. The hash table select can be updated fairly easily to meet your needs.

Comment: Its a giant mess thanks to little or no standards being created or followed. The first "a-*" account is a elevated permissions account, its manager attribute is the DN of the users primary (non elevated account). I need to find the samaccount name of the primary account, then add "s-" to the samaccount name. This s-samaccountname may or may have not been created previously so I need to check if its already there.. Because even the samaccount name doesnt have any strictly followed standards I need to collect all of the account names so I can compare them to make sure its the right account

Comment: Oh and thanks for the code.. its big improvement over what I had so far.. .Now how to find out if the S account exists and then get all of this data into a csv, one row for each users accounts.

Comment: The s account lookup is in the code. You may need to tweak it since I don’t know your domain setup